# visual presentation timer with segments either for MacOS or online

Tags: data-visualization, macos, presentation, timer

I am looking for a visual presentation timer with segments either for MacOS  or online. I have been using [pTimer+](https://itunes.apple.com/jp/app/jianerupurezentaima/id557849104?mt=8) [link to app store] on my phone, see screenshots below, but I haven't been able to find something as compact and functional as pTimer+ for macOS or online.

I did find [this](https://www.timeanddate.com/timer/), but it's kinda clunky and big. Also, I would like to be able to have it running on my laptop next to the presentation window when using any software that allow for a split screen, with slides on one screen and presentation on another. In other words, what I'm looking for is something rather compact and visual, preferably something that can stand along the edge of the monitor or lay at the bottom of the monitor indicating the individual segments of my presentation and help me stay on track.

Any pointers or input would be appreciated!

[image: pTimer+ organize] [image: pTimer+ countdown]

Comment: Do you need it to support segments naming/colors/etc? What are your hard requirements about that? Free? cheap? any amount?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I kinda do not have any other requirements then it being either macOS or online and able to be next to the presenter, as described. Unfortunately, after putting out the bounty, I have too little credit to up-vote you. But you definitely number one for the bounty !

Comment: Ha funny situation! So great to know you don't have any other requirements and it fits :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Online-Stopwatch](https://www.online-stopwatch.com)

- Free
- Online - web based

You can use the [small version](https://www.online-stopwatch.com/interval-timer/), or the [full-screen version](https://www.online-stopwatch.com/full-screen-interval-timer/).

### Demonstration:

- Note that the blinking red is at the beginning and end of each segment, and it looks a lot just because my segments were just 2-3 seconds. It will look better with longer segments.
- The full-screen version is actually centered in the page, but it takes half of the space - which is great because if you put it on half of the screen it just fills it.

[image]