# Countdown timer for conference

Tags: presentation, powerpoint

Most conference have a countdown timer so that their speakers can know how well they're doing. I'm looking for software to do that.

I know presenter view of PowerPoint has a timer, but I don't want people to switch to presenting or reset it when they're about to start.

It would be great if it was:

- Clean
- Big
- Remote controlled

Comment: This doesn't work because it assumes the speaker will control it: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/50911/visual-presentation-timer-with-segments-either-for-macos-or-online

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found out one called [chronograph.io](https://chronograph.io/). It is very simple: it contains multiple dials for setting the timer or countdown and once you start, it generates a read only link and a read+write, which are synchronized.